# cookies not being set on azure but set fine on localhost in web api with blazor web assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

First of all, i created the blazor web assembly app. This is my program.cs

```
  using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using ibraakapp.Data;
using Ibraakweb;
using Ibraakweb.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CookieHandler>();


builder.Services.AddHttpClient("API", options => {
    options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ibraakapi20230321041048.azurewebsites.net/");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<CookieHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<Ipilogics, ApiLogic>();



//builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });    
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

This is my login component

```
   @page "/login"
@inject Ipilogics _apiLogic

@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
       <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="txtEmail" class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input @bind="loginModel.UserName" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="txtPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input @bind="loginModel.Password" type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" @onclick="UserLogin" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>


@code 
{
    private LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
 
    private async Task UserLogin()
    {
        var message = await _apiLogic.LoginAsync(loginModel);
        if (message == "Success")
        {
   
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/",true);
        }
    }
}
```

Thirdly the iplogics part

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}


public interface Ipilogics
{
    Task<string> LoginAsync(LoginModel login);
}

public class ApiLogic : Ipilogics
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    public ApiLogic(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<string> LoginAsync(LoginModel login)
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("API");
        string payload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(login);
        var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("api/Auth/login", content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            return "failed";
        }
    }
}
```

this is the cookie handler

```
 public class CookieHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Now going on the web api stuff

this is my authController which is being called from login

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ibraakContext _cookieAuthContext;
        public AuthController(ibraakContext cookieAuthContext)
        {
            _cookieAuthContext = cookieAuthContext;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(LoginDto login)
        {
           

            var claims = new List<Claim>
             {
                 new Claim("userid","1")
          
             };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)

            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                authProperties);



            return Ok("Success");
        }
}
}
```

and lastly this is program.cs stuff in web api

```
   using ibraakapi.Data.db;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ibraakContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
)
 .AddCookie();


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsSpecs",
    builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(options => true)
            .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

//builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
//{
//    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
//   options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
//    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    
//});



// Above the below line register Cors

var app = builder.Build();



// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();



app.UseCors("CorsSpecs");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The problem is that when i was using web api from localhost the cookies was being set fine. but i put the web api on azure app service the cookies is not being set? can some one help.

Comment: Show code for CustomAuthStateProvider and for application layout